# When is OK to repeat words or lines in prayer?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, song-poetry, shabbat-songs

I have read several questions and answers on here regarding repeating words in prayer, but they do not answer why some common repetitions are allowable.

Some examples:

1)  During the Torah service, it is common to repeat "Ki mi-Tziyon tetze Torah" and "Barukh she-natan Torah, Torah".

2)  During Aleinu, it is common to hear "u-Shkhinat uzo, u-Shkhinat uzo" and most infamously "u'shmo, u'shmo, u'shmo ehad."

3)  Possibly most problematic, in some synagogues there is a custom of singing and repeating "V'techezena ainainu b'shuvkha l'Tzion b'rachamim." during the Chazarat ha-Shatz and also of "Sim, sim, sim shalom, sim shalom tovah u'brakhah."

The answer to [Repeating words in prayer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34593/repeating-words-in-prayer) makes a convincing case that unnessessary repetition was looked down on by many authorities, especially for the Chazzan.

The answer to [Is repeating the chorus in Lecha Dodi problematic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11257/is-repeating-the-chorus-in-lecha-dodi-problematic) makes a distinction between a *piyut* and a *tfilla* and points to the relevance of whether a name of God was used.  Those criteria make sense, but by them there are problems with the minhagim listed above:

1) Since the Torah service is a *davar shbikedusha* (a prayer that can only be recited in the presence of a minyan) should these not be repeated?

2) Isn't "Shkhina" a name of God ("the Presence").  Also can't "u'shmo" x3 be construed as trinitarian as Jake and Josh Waxman [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11257/is-repeating-the-chorus-in-lecha-dodi-problematic#comment16716_11313)?  Ironic, in a piyut composed against idolatry.

3) It seems like these ones *might* be the most flagrant violations of halacha since it is in the Shemona Esrei and since "Shalom" is a name of God.  Is this changed by the fact that this happens during the repetition rather than during the silent Shemona Esrai?

Am I getting carried away with what might be harmless customs or are these actual deviations from halacha?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of the linked question.